# Uploaded Images are not sent to folder

Tags: express, file-upload, body-parser

My `req.files.foo.mv` (`express-fileupload`) is not moving the images files to `public/img` folder. The body-parser is passing the image name and image path to my post page(EJS `<%= blogpost.image %>` ) but the images are not sent to `public/img` folder.

```js
// index.js 
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const BlogPost = require('./models/BlogPost')
const expressSession = require('express-session')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const app = new express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database', {useNewUrlParser:true})
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(fileUpload())
app.use(expressSession({secret:'keyboard cat'}))  
global.loggedIn = null
app.use("*", (req, res, next) =>{
    loggedIn = req.session.userId
    next()
});
app.use(flash()); 
const storeUserController = require('./controllers/storeUser')
app.post('/posts/store', authMiddleware, storePostsController)

// post store controller
const BlogPost = require('../models/BlogPost')
const path = require('path')
module.exports = (req,res) => {
    let image = req.files.image
    image.mv(path.resolve (__dirname, 'public/img', image.name), async (error) => {
       await BlogPost.create({
         ...req.body, 
         image:'/img/' + image.name
       })
       res.redirect('/')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried  express-fileupload, but I am sure that multer can do this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 0):

- Try the latest version express-fileupload (1.1.6 or later).
- Set option createParentPath: true to create a directory for uploads if it not exist.
- Set option debug: true and check in output what happens during upload and moving.